# add conditional body class in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want's to add conditional body classes for **index.php, page.php, category.php, tag.php**

- In **index.php** body class only want's **<body class"home">** In
  **page.php** body class only want's **<body class"page">** In **category.ph**p body class only want's **<body class"cat">** In **tag.php body** class only want's **<body class"tag">** In **search.php** body class only want's **<body class"search">**

Answer (score 0):

If you write the `body` tag in your template (usually in the `header.php` file) as follows , these classes *will*  be added automatically:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

(note that the category class will be "category", not "cat")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `body_class` filter to accomplish this.  Example below:

```
add_filter("body_class", function($classnames) {
    $conditions = [
        "search" => is_search(),
        "home" => is_front_page(),
        "cat" => is_category(),
        "tag" => is_tag(),
        "page" => is_page()
    ];

    foreach ($conditions as $classname => $condition) {
        if ($condition) {
            return [ $classname ];
        }
    }

    // return default classnames if none of the above conditions are met
    return $classnames;
});
```

WordPress docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you put "body_class" function in the body tag

```
<body <?= body_class(); ?>>
```

then you can add classes to your pages using "body_class" filter

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
if ( is_page_template( 'page-example.php' ) ) {
     $classes[] = 'example';
}
return $classes;
}
```

Your class will show up in this tag

```
<body class="page page-id-2 page-parent page-template-default logged-in">
```

For Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/